# Python : Amount input with While

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

Beginner here. I'm trying to build a loop where the chekout displays a total amount that has to be over 0$. For example, if I start with 450$ the code works. But if I start with say -12 it will ask me again (which is what I want), but then if I enter 450 as the third essay; the first condition keeps runing. Why is that? Thanks in advance.

```
amount = input("What's the total amount of the bill ? :")
value = float(amount)

while (value < 0):
    print("Please enter an amount higher than 0$ !")
    amount = input("What's the total amount of the bill ? :")
    
else:
    print("Total amount of the bill:{0}".format(value))
```

Comment: `while..else` is not what you think it is. Also you never update `value` inside the `while` loop.

Comment: You might want to read: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to update the variable "value" so your while loop condition remains true even after inputting 450 (value is still -12). You can convert the input to a float in the same line too, which removes the need for the "amount" variable

```
value = float(input("What's the total amount of the bill ? :"))

while (value < 0):
    print("Please enter an amount higher than 0$ !")
    value = float(input("What's the total amount of the bill ? :"))
    
else:
    print("Total amount of the bill:{0}".format(value))
```

Comment: thank you for the clear explanation! I appreciate it.